How can I effectively use circuit conditions to control a space platform schedule?
I am trying to configure my transportation space platform to wait for ammo to be backed up before moving using a circuit condition in the schedule:

The image shows that the space platform hub is connected to a circuit network and the ammo circuit is present in the network, but in the schedule the corresponding circuit condition is shown as unmet and the platform doesn't move. So, I think I'm missing something with this functionality. How can I make the schedule use the circuit signals the way I want?

You need to select the checkbox "Send to platform" in order to use the circuit network for wait conditions.
The tooltip literally says "Sends the contents of the circuit network to the platform, so they can be used for wait conditions."


That did it. It just did not click for me that you had to explicitly take an extra step to have the hub send the signals it receives to itself.

@murgatroid99 Yeah I don't know why exactly they have done it that way, I don't see any purpose of that extra step. I guess they just copied how it works for trains and didn't think too much about it.

There are two things you could try:
Since you are interested in what is on board, you could simply set the ammo condition to Cargo instead of Circuit, the same way science packs are set up in your image. I recommend this approach first in case you want to use the circuit network for something else later.
Alternately, you should be able to get circuits to work. The condition is looking for signals on the network, so you need your ship to advertise its contents there. In the list of check boxes on the right, select "read contents". This will treat the ship like any other container in the game and emit signals matching the types and quantities of the items in its inventory.

In the circuit network in the question, it has a value of 8 so the circuit network itself already has values. While using cargo instead of circuit for wait condition is one option, what is really missing to get the circuit network working is what I mention in my answer.
